# BigQuery: schema autodetection of JSON couldn't recognize a field appearing later in the JSON input file

Tags: google-bigquery

I found that BigQuery's schema autodetection doesn't recognize a field if that doesn't appear in the beginning of an input JSON file.

I have this field named "details" which is a record type. In the first 2K rows of the JSON input file, this field doesn't have any sub-fields. But then in 2,698 rows of the input file, this field has "report" sub-field for the first time. If I move the line to the top of the JSON file, it works fine.

How can I solve this issue? Explicitly specifying the schema is one way but I am wondering if there is a way to make the auto detection scan more rows or something like that.

Comment: Sounds that this is a good input for the issue tracker: https://issuetracker.google.com/savedsearches/559654 especially if you have the two job ids that fail and work

Comment: The schema has to be detected before the query runs, and it's not practical to scan all the rows before the query runs. The limit is about 100ish rows. Can you re-order the file so the row with all fields appear in the first 100 rows? Another workaround is to split the row out and load it first. After the table is created, it's schema will be used to load other JSON files if no schema is specified.

Comment: Providing an option (as the number of lines to scan) to control this would be good enough. That's an approach used by Redshift in AWS for some options (for example in auto compression)